# New Deploy to Production, Rake db:migrate fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rake

Trying to deploy a new app to production.  Build the server from a base CentOS.
However, when I try to run the rake to migrate the database, i get the following error

```
[root@tatp tatp_store]# bundle exec rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant ActiveShipping::Base

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
[root@tatp tatp_store]#
```

I through it might be a similar issue to the DSL issue but similar fixes do not work.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you forget to run `bundle install` before running migration?

Comment: didn't think so; did a bundle install and tried the rake again, same error

Comment: Might be a Spree issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/spree-user/q9AU0xeuHr4

Comment: looks like it could be a bug: https://github.com/spree/spree_active_shipping/issues/26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by a bug in the Spree Active Shipping, issue #26 which has been fixed in build 9d4af80